# Implement filter using project reactor

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a list of items from Mongo and I need to filter them by remote call result, something like this:

```java
repository.findByString(String string) // Flux<SomeObject>
    .filter(a -> {
        Boolean result =  remoteClient.getInfo(a.getSomeProperty()).block().getBoolean();
        return result;
    }).map(a -> {
        //Some logic
    })
```

I don't know how to do it in a non-blocking way.
Please help

Comment: Flux result =  remoteClient.getInfo(a.getSomeProperty()).block().getBoolean(); changeto Mono.fromFuture(..remoteClient.getInfo(a.getSomeProperty()) in a thread....).flatMapMany(Flux::just)

Comment: @zt9788 That requires extra threads while `remoteClient.getInfo` is already reactive as I see

Comment: Sorry What I said is wrong, please see others' answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `filterWhen` for that purpose:

```
    repository.findByString(String string) // Flux<SomeObject>
            .filterWhen(a -> remoteClient.getInfo(a.getSomeProperty()).map(s -> s.getBoolean()))
            .map(a -> {
                //Some logic
            })
```